# always return Instance of model instead of the data i want

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to getData from database with the help of sqflite.

Even though , I use async and await, it always returns a list of instance of my Model.

I have check in the db file , but it's fine. just get problem in this .

```
late StoryDatabase storyDatabase = StoryDatabase();


  @override

     void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
         storyDatabase = StoryDatabase();
      
        getDataTest();
      }
    
    
     void getDataTest() async {
        test = await storyDatabase.getData();
        print("test result1 $test");
    
        setState(() {
          print("test result $test");
        });
      }
```

Can anyone explain it for me , please ? @@

Answer (score 1):

Use `DichangeDependencies` for Async Function not `initState`

```js
late StoryDatabase storyDatabase = StoryDatabase();

bool _isinit = true;
  
  @override
     void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
         storyDatabase = StoryDatabase();
      
      }
      
      void didChangeDependencies() async{
        if (_isinit) {
            await getDataTest();
          _isinit = false;
        }
        super.didChangeDependencies();
      }
    
    
     void getDataTest() async {
        test = await storyDatabase.getData();
        print("test result1 $test");
    
        setState(() {
          print("test result $test");
        });
      }
```

Comment: I just told the right place where to put async function ..... without the whole code i cant help you

Comment: It's ok. I just figured out it comes from my model @@. Thank you

Comment: if my answer helped you to solve the issue you can give me a thumbs up

Comment: actually, it didn't help, but I will still give you a thumbs up for your help . Thanks , bro